# Cannot connect to SQL Server in update-database

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting this error when running Update-Database command from package manager console:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid).

The connection string I have used is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CarConnectionString": "server=servername\\SQLEXPRESS, database=CarModel, Trusted_connection=true" 
}
```

Any help, suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: "The server was not found or was not accessible". Is "servername" correct in that connection string?

Comment: Most likely, you just need to use **semicolons** (`;`) to separate your elements in the connection string - not commas. Try this : `"server=servername\\SQLEXPRESS; database=CarModel; Trusted_connection=true"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions in the comments.

The correct connection string is:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CarConnectionString": "server=server\\SQLEXPRESS, 1433; database= CarModel; Trusted_connection=true"
}
```